# How to create an asp.net form to retrieve list item to a gridview? Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, development, asp.net

First I want to know how to create an asp.net form and connect it with SharePoint, I want to create an asp.net form just like InfoPath forms.

Second I want to retrieve all items from my list to grid view in my asp.net form

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to do that is to develop visual web part then host it inside SharePoint Site web part page . The visual web part will work like ASP.page inside SharePoint .

**To Create Visual Web Part.**

- Open Visual studio > New Project > Empty SharePoint SSolution.
- Right Click on your project and select Add new item > add Visual Web Part.

**To retrieve SharePOint list items and bind it to grid view.**

- Open the created Visual web part > from tool box add grid view .
- In code write the following code with your list name and grid view name.

> ```
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
>         {  
>             SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;  
>             SPList list = web.Lists["Employee"];  
>             SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;  
>             mygrid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();  
>             mygrid.DataBind();  
>
>   }
> ```

- Deploy your solution.
- Go to your web part page inside your SharePoint > Edit it.
- Click Add web part and select your web part.

It's should now show your created web part that has a grid view with your list items

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: Thanks, this is working properly but I down't want this to be as a webpart, but I want on a blank page with some asp forms. to be a white page with some controls. I don't know if you are understanding me what I want.

Comment: you can create application page or asp.net and host it in page viewer web part as I frame

Comment: Any tutorial how how to do this or any link?

Comment: Are you have a normal ASP.Net web application now ?

Comment: No I am not having it

Comment: You can check this to create application page inside SharePoint https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231557.aspx , but If you already have ASP.NET page you can host its URL within page viewer web part ,

Comment: Should you tell me your real scenario to can help you to select the most prefers based on your situation ? If i can !